The chain rule for vector valued functions
I am currently looking at the following gradient:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial W} || y-  W z||^2$$
With $W \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}, z \in \mathbb{R}^n, y \in \mathbb{R}^m$.
I am aware that one can obtain the solution via a straight forward calculation like this:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial W} || y-  W z||^2 &= \frac{\partial}{\partial W} ( y-  W z)^T ( y-  W z) \\
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial W} \left[y^Ty -2 y^T W z + (W z)^T (W z) \right] \\
    &= -2  y z^T + 2 W z z^T \\
    &= 2(W z - y) z^T
\end{align*}
But I explicitly want to apply the chain rule. Let $h := Wz$.
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial h} || y-  h||^2 &= (y - h)^T(y - h) \\
    &= \frac{\partial}{\partial h^L} \left(y^T y  - y^T h - h^T y  + h^T h\right) \\
    &= 2(h - y)  \\
    &= 2(Wz -y)
\end{align*}
And
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial W} h &= \frac{\partial}{\partial W} W z \\
    &= z^T \otimes I_{m}
\end{align*}
As far as I understand the chain rule for vector valued functions, the product the Jacobians of $|| y-  h||^2$ and $Wz$ should yield the overall gradient with respect to $W$.
But multiplying $2(Wz -y)$ and $z^T \otimes I_{m}$ does not equal $2(W z - y) z^T$ unless the kronecker product is dropped. What am I missing here?

Your mistake is assuming a naive matrix multiplication when in reality it's a tensor contraction. $2(Wz-y) ⋅ (zᵀ⊗I_m)$ does indeed equal $2(Wz-y)z^T$ when properly defining $"⊗"$ and $"⋅"$.

This kind of question has been asked many times, I recommend you search within answers of users greg, Ben Grossman or mine.

Its easier if you first apply the chain rule to $\phi(x)=x^Tx$ and then to $x=y-Wz$.
